# Count frequency of a character by group

Tags: r

I want to count reasons for infertility by group, however some people have more than one reason. What is the best way code this to present this in a table

```
ID<- c('id1','id2','id3','id4','id5','id6')
rsn <- c('endo','endo, male','male','unexplained','other','male, endo, other')
group<- c('group1','group2','group2','group3','group1','group3')
data <- data.frame(ID, rsn, group)
```

The output would be something like

```
                     group1 group2 group3 
endo                      1      1      1
male                      0      2      0
other                     1      0      1        
unexplained               0      0      1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tidyverse**

```r
ID<- c('id1','id2','id3','id4','id5','id6')
rsn <- c('endo','endo, male','male','unexplained','other','male, endo, other')
group<- c('group1','group2','group2','group3','group1','group3')

data <- data.frame(ID, rsn, group)

library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  separate_rows(rsn) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = rsn,
    names_from = group,
    values_from = group,
    values_fn = length,
    values_fill = 0
  )
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   rsn         group1 group2 group3
#>   <chr>        <int>  <int>  <int>
#> 1 endo             1      1      1
#> 2 male             0      2      1
#> 3 unexplained      0      0      1
#> 4 other            1      0      1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**data.table**

```r
library(magrittr)
library(data.table)

setDT(data)[, 
            list(rsn = unlist(tstrsplit(rsn, split = ", "))), 
            by = list(ID, group)
            ] %>%
  dcast(data = ., formula = rsn ~ group, fun.aggregate = length)
#>            rsn group1 group2 group3
#> 1:        endo      1      1      1
#> 2:        male      0      2      1
#> 3:       other      1      0      1
#> 4: unexplained      0      0      1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Nice, you did it in fewer lines than me. I haven't really made use of `id_cols`

Answer (score 3):

Other answers have shown how to achieve the result by reshaping data.

If you
are just after a summary table, a straightforward way would be to use
`xtabs()` after creating a row for each entry in `rsn`, e.g. with `separate_rows()`:

```r
library(tidyr)

ID <- c("id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5", "id6")
rsn <- c("endo", "endo, male", "male", "unexplained", "other", "male, endo, other")
group <- c("group1", "group2", "group2", "group3", "group1", "group3")

data <- data.frame(ID, rsn, group)

data %>% 
  separate_rows(rsn) %>% 
  xtabs(formula = ~ rsn + group)
#>              group
#> rsn           group1 group2 group3
#>   endo             1      1      1
#>   male             0      2      1
#>   other            1      0      1
#>   unexplained      0      0      1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ID<- c('id1','id2','id3','id4','id5','id6')
rsn <- c('endo','endo, male','male','unexplained','other','male, endo, other')
group<- c('group1','group2','group2','group3','group1','group3')
data <- data.frame(ID, rsn, group)


library(data.table)

setDT(data)

dcast(data[, .(rsn = unlist(str_split(rsn, ", "))), by = group], rsn ~ group, value.var = "rsn", fun.aggregate = length)

           rsn group1 group2 group3
1:        endo      1      1      1
2:        male      0      2      1
3:       other      1      0      1
4: unexplained      0      0      1
```

Comment: Really appreciate the help!!