# How to One-Hot Encoding stacked columns in R

Tags: r, one-hot-encoding

I have data that look like this

```
+---+-------+
|   |  col1 |
+---+-------+
| 1 |     A |
| 2 |   A,B |
| 3 |   B,C |
| 4 |     B |
| 5 | A,B,C |
+---+-------+
```

Expected Output

```
+---+-----------+
|   | A | B | C |
+---+-----------+
|1  | 1 | 0 | 0 |
|2  | 1 | 1 | 0 |
|3  | 0 | 1 | 1 |
|4  | 0 | 1 | 0 |
|5  | 1 | 1 | 1 |
+---+---+---+---+
```

How can I encode it like this?

Comment: What is the type of your `col1`? Is it a character vector each entry having some comma-delimited alphabets or a list of character vectors?

Comment: Similar question from just this morning: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70789253/count-frequency-of-a-character-by-group

Comment: it just normal string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this could help

```
df %>%
  mutate(r = 1:n()) %>%
  unnest(col1) %>%
  table() %>%
  t()
```

which gives

```
   col1
r   A B C
  1 1 0 0
  2 1 1 0
  3 0 1 1
  4 0 1 0
  5 1 1 1
```

## Data

```
df <- tibble(
  col1 = list(
    "A",
    c("A", "B"),
    c("B", "C"),
    "B",
    c("A", "B", "C")
  )
)
```

---

If your data is given in the following format

```
df <- data.frame(
  col1 = c("A", "A,B", "B,C", "B", "A,B,C")
)
```

then you can try

```
with(
  df,
  table(rev(stack(setNames(strsplit(col1, ","), seq_along(col1)))))
)
```

which gives

```
   values
ind A B C
  1 1 0 0
  2 1 1 0
  3 0 1 1
  4 0 1 0
  5 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `table()` with `map_df()` from purrr to count the occurrences
in each element of a list, and return a data frame. Putting it into a
function with some post-processing, and using dplyrs data frame unpacking in
`mutate()`, you could do something like this to stay within a data frame
context:

```r
library(tidyverse)

one_hot <- function(x) {
  map_df(x, table) %>% 
    mutate_all(as.integer) %>% 
    mutate_all(replace_na, 0L)
}

df <- data.frame(col1 = c("A", "A,B", "B,C", "B", "A,B,C"))

df %>% 
  mutate(
    one_hot(strsplit(col1, ","))
  )
#>    col1 A B C
#> 1     A 1 0 0
#> 2   A,B 1 1 0
#> 3   B,C 0 1 1
#> 4     B 0 1 0
#> 5 A,B,C 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

An additional base R solution:

```
+(
  with(
    df, 
    sapply(
      unique(
        unlist(
          strsplit(
            col1, 
            ","
            )
          )
        ),
      `grepl`, 
      col1
    )
  )
)
```